# Symfony login form — Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on null

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to load some method (which creates a login form for me) from one source controller into another one.

Here is my source SecurityController:

```
namespace ImmoBundle\Controller\Security;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use ImmoBundle\Entity\User;
use ImmoBundle\Form\Type\LoginType;

class SecurityController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/login", name="login")
     */
    public function loginAction(Request $request)
    {
        $parametersArray = $this->loadForm($request);

        return $this->render(
            'ImmoBundle::Security/login.html.twig',
            array(
                'login_form' => $parametersArray['form']->createView(),
                'error'      => $parametersArray['error'],
                'last_email' => $parametersArray['lastEmail'],
            )
        );
    }


    public function loadForm($request)
    {
        $user = new User();
        $form = $this->createForm(LoginType::class, $user);
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        $authenticationUtils = $this->get('security.authentication_utils');
        $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();

        $lastEmail = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();
        $parametersArray['form'] = $form;
        $parametersArray['error'] = $error;
        $parametersArray['lastEmail'] = $lastEmail;

        return $parametersArray;
    }
}
```

Then I've defined my source controller as a Service in services.yml:

```
login_form_service:
    class: ImmoBundle\Controller\Security\SecurityController
```

My target controller looks like this:

```
namespace ImmoBundle\Controller\Pages;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class ListingPageController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/id/{listingId}", name="idPage", requirements={
     *     "listingId": "\d+"
     * })
     */
    public function loadIdAction($listingId, Request $request)
    {
        $yourController = $this->get('login_form_service');

        print_r($yourController->loadForm($request));

        return $this->render(
            'ImmoBundle::page.html.twig',
            array()
        );
    }
}
```

But instead of an object in line

> print_r($yourController->loadForm($request))

I've got this error: `Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on null`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You SecurityController registered as service "login_form_service" don't know about service_container

Try:

```
login_form_service:
    class: ImmoBundle\Controller\Security\SecurityController
    calls: 
       - [setContainer, [@service_container]]
```